# Javascript and Image Change, time of day based

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have the Javascript detect the time of day, then load the right CSS Sheet. In addition to that, I need it to replace a image.

```
function getStylesheet() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getHours();


      var square = "<img src='images/Image-square-night.gif' width='400' height='400' >"

      if (20 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 7) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='layout-night.css' type='text/css'>");
       function sq(){
        if(document.getElementById("image-hold")){
            "image-hold".innerHTML = square
      }}
      if (8 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 19){
          document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='layout-day.css' type='text/css'>")}

      }

}
```

Comment: And? Is something not working? If so, how is it not working? Do you ever call `getStylesheet`? Do you do make that call *during* the main parsing of the page (since it uses `document.write`), not afterward?

Comment: Formatting your code reasonably helps both you and us read it, minimizing confusion and errors.

Comment: Amongst other things, you have a syntax error in that code: You have a function *declaration* within a conditional block. That's not allowed in JavaScript, though some (not all!) browsers may rewrite it as a function expression for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first `if` statement seems wrong:

```
  if (20 <= currentTime&&currentTime <= 7) {
```

Most probably it should be

```
  if (
      (0 <= currentTime && currentTime < 8) || 
      (19 < currentTime && currentTime <= 24)
  ) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this:

```
function getStylesheet() {
    // Creating  LINK node
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.type = "text/css";
    // Get current time hour
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();     
    if (20 <= currentTime && currentTime <= 7) {
        link.href = 'layout-night.css';
        // replacing the image in this case
        var square = "<img src='images/Image-square-night.gif' width='400' height='400' >";
        var imageHolder = document.getElementById("image-hold");
        if(imageHolder != null){
            imageHolder.innerHTML = square
        }
    } else {
        link.href = 'layout-day.css';
    }
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```